Conflicting disabilities
While rare, you sometimes see situations where you cannot feasibly accommodate two employees at once. For example, you might end up with one employee who depends on a service dog, and another who has a serious airborne allergy to dogs.
In such cases,  how do you choose whom to prioritize without breaking the law?
Edit: my example is purely an example. Presume that there are two different people with two different disabilities, and it is infeasible to reasonably accommodate both.

AFAIK the usual standard is "reasonable accommodation". Anything that would hurt another employee is patently unreasonable. On that basis, the law allows you to decline either request.
